# fatal: Authentication failed Google Cloud Repo

Tags: git, google-app-engine

Running Mac OS X Yosemite. So far I've installed git and google sdk, created a project in google's developer console, created a local git repository, and I'm trying to link the local repository to google cloud using 'git push --all google'
I keep getting "fatal: Authentication failed".
I'm not using two factor authentication. I've gone through the process of 'git auth login'. Not sure what else to do. I haven't signed up for a free trial of google cloud, does this matter? Just testing things out for now.
Appreciate anyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/) mention, "Each project you create in the Google Developers Console has an associated Cloud Source Repository". If, as you mention, you "haven't signed up for a free trial of google cloud", then presumably you have created no project in the Google Developers Console, and therefore there is no "associated Cloud Source Repository" for you to push to.

Comment: That sounds right, however I was able to go to developers.google.com, sign into my account, and create a TEST project regardless.